# Eclipse, consuming a web service gives java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, apache-axis

Would like some help. I already spent a lot of hours trying to solve this problem, searching in the web, some sites - and some questions here - but still no answer for this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I'm not by that means a specialist in this, so some information may be vague I'll try to be to use the best terms to describe the problem.

When I try to consume a webservice I myself created using Eclipse, in Java language, using Apache Tomcat 6, it gives me an error:

> The content of the body cannot be displayed in the form view. Please switch to the source view to examine the raw content.

I tested the webservice (the 11 methods) as an Java application and JUnit Test and it was fine. The methods delete, add, modify, and search for some information in a database on MYSQL. As I said, the methods run properly as an Java application.

I tried to generate a client on a different project. If I try to consume the web service from the client, it gives me this error:

```
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:Mauricio-PC

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)  at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.endElement(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:129)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.endElement(DeserializationContext.java:1087)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
at client.ServicioSoapBindingStub.ingresarAlumnoCurso(ServicioSoapBindingStub.java:488)
at client.ServicioProxy.ingresarAlumnoCurso(ServicioProxy.java:80)
at client.Prueba.main(Prueba.java:19)
```

I remember someone saying it was cause my hostname is called "Mauricio-PC" and Tomcat couldn't recognize it. But I don't really know if that's true.

So, any help is greatly appreciated. Feel free to ask any questions.

Thanks.

EDIT: I had created another project with another name, ServicioCapacitacion instead of SistemaCapacitacion. Same files. I reimported the .jars.

So I have this libraries:

```
Library Apache Tomcat v6.0:
  annotations-api.jar
  catalina-ant.jar
  catalina-ha.jar
  catalina-tribes.jar
  catalina.jar
  ecj-3.7.2.jar
  el-api.jar
  gson-2.2.3.jar
  jasper-el.jar
  jasper.jar
  jsp-api.jar
  mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar
  orm.jar
  servlet-api.jar
  tomcat-coyote.jar
  tomcat-dbcp.jar
  tomcat-i18n-es.jar
  tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
  tomcat-i18n-ja.jar

JRE System Library:
  resources.jar
  rt.jar
  jsse.jar
  jce.jar
  charsets.jar
  jfr.jar
  access-bridge-64.jar
  dnsns.jar
  jaccess.jar
  localedata.jar
  sunec.jar
  sunjce_provider.jar
  sunmscapi.jar
  zipfs.jar

JUnit 4:

  junit.jar
  org.hamcrest.core_1.1.0.v20090501071000.jar

Web App Libraries:
  axis.jar
  commons-discovery-0.2.jar
  commons-logging.jar
  jaxrpc.jar
  saaj.jar
  wsdl4j.jar



gwt-dev.jar    <- These are alone, not inside any Library
gwt-servlet.jar
mail.jar
```

AND inside the directory WebContent>WEB-INF>lib there are these libraries:

```
axis.jar
commons-discovery-0.2.jar
commons-logging.jar
jaxrpc.jar
saaj.jar
wsdl4j.jar
```

I know already these libraries are repeated, my question is, do I have to delete one of these groups? what group do I eliminate/move and what group I keep? is there a "good" method to remove them?

NEW Display of the localhost:8080/ServicioCapacitacion/index.jsp

```
Estado HTTP 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

type Informe de Excepción

mensaje javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

descripción El servidor encontró un error interno que hizo que no pudiera rellenar este requerimiento.

excepción

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:412)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
causa raíz

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:865)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:794)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:71)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
causa raíz

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    negocio.Capacitacion.verActa(Capacitacion.java:329)
    servicio.Servicio.verActa(Servicio.java:70)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:62)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
causa raíz

org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Invalid class loader hierarchy.  You have more than one version of 'org.apache.commons.logging.Log' visible, which is not allowed. (Caused by org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Invalid class loader hierarchy.  You have more than one version of 'org.apache.commons.logging.Log' visible, which is not allowed.) (Caused by org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Invalid class loader hierarchy.  You have more than one version of 'org.apache.commons.logging.Log' visible, which is not allowed. (Caused by org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Invalid class loader hierarchy.  You have more than one version of 'org.apache.commons.logging.Log' visible, which is not allowed.))
    org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:543)
    org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:235)
    org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:209)
    org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
    org.orm.PersistentManager.<clinit>(PersistentManager.java:34)
    negocio.Capacitacion.verActa(Capacitacion.java:329)
    servicio.Servicio.verActa(Servicio.java:70)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:62)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
causa raíz

org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Invalid class loader hierarchy.  You have more than one version of 'org.apache.commons.logging.Log' visible, which is not allowed. (Caused by org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Invalid class loader hierarchy.  You have more than one version of 'org.apache.commons.logging.Log' visible, which is not allowed.)
    org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:397)
    org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:529)
    org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:235)
    org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:209)
    org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
    org.orm.PersistentManager.<clinit>(PersistentManager.java:34)
    negocio.Capacitacion.verActa(Capacitacion.java:329)
    servicio.Servicio.verActa(Servicio.java:70)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:62)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
causa raíz

org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: Invalid class loader hierarchy.  You have more than one version of 'org.apache.commons.logging.Log' visible, which is not allowed.
    org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:385)
    org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:529)
    org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:235)
    org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:209)
    org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
    org.orm.PersistentManager.<clinit>(PersistentManager.java:34)
    negocio.Capacitacion.verActa(Capacitacion.java:329)
    servicio.Servicio.verActa(Servicio.java:70)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:62)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
nota La traza completa de la causa de este error se encuentra en los archivos de diario de Apache Tomcat/6.0.36.

Apache Tomcat/6.0.36
```

Comment: Can you paste the WSDL?

Comment: Sure thing!  But it's too long to be able to write here. Instead I'll just upload a txt file for you to see it.

[link](http://www.tourmoon.biosoft.cl/service.txt)

thanks!

Comment: To get past the error ***"The content of the body cannot be displayed in the form view. Please switch to the source view to examine the raw content."***, look for a tab, usually in the bottom of the window, probably the "FORM" tab is selected. Look for a "SOURCE" tab; Let me know if it works.

Comment: Can you also paste us the line 488 and surroundings (like methods) of `ServicioSoapBindingStub.java`? I'm asking based on the stack trace `client.ServicioSoapBindingStub.ingresarAlumnoCurso(ServicioSoapBindingStub.java:488)`

Comment: Or, better yet, what tool did you use to generate the client code from the WSDL? The problem is possibly not related to your host being called `Mauricio-PC`, I believe the error message is misleading in that way.

Comment: There is the SOAP Request Envelope:

Comment: SOAP Request Envelope, where?

Comment: Here it's the soap:
[link](http://www.tourmoon.biosoft.cl/Soapenvelope.txt)

The whole explanation is in the link

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The problem is very likely not in the Axis generated code, but in you business method (`verActa()`?). Can you execute the business method (not the web service, forget about it for now) with `alu_dni=1` and `cur_codasign=1` without errors?

Comment: I mean, you are getting a falty envelope as response. This highly indicates that the error is not in the client, but in the server (the web service or the business method). Have you got access to the server where the service is running? Can you check it's log for errors?

Comment: its gives me "esp":-2,"desc_resp":"No se encontró alguno de los objetos"}
" wich is exactly what is expected, cause there are not objects "alumno" with dni = 1 or curso with coasign = 1. Again, I have tested every method as a java application, as well utilizing JUnit test to see incoherences on try-catchs, but everything is fine.

The problem is when I try to consume my service from the wsdl, using persistence layer. Without persistence layer the problem is gone.

Comment: The log doesn't show anything after a clean of it and testing the wsdl, as well the client.

Comment: But, you see, if you send a well-formed envelope, and the server returns one with a fault, the problem can't be on the client, do you agree? The client's only job is to create a well-formed envelope, and it is doing so. Can you paste us your `@WebService` class? (it's ok pasting in the question, you can let it be big.)

Comment: Ok, I edited it on the question. Search on the last part of it :)

Comment: I see it now. So, as you said, when you call `Servicio.ingresarAlumnoCurso("1","1")` directly it works as expected, right? In that `Soapenvelope.txt` you mention two envelopes (one sent, other received), how did you try them out (used another tool)?

Comment: Yeah, it works as expected. For instance, since there is no student (alumno), gives some error ("-2, object already in the DB" or something. 

I tested in the Eclipse Web Service Explorer. Right click on the wsdl, test with and use such tool. I can choose ANY method from the wsdl (I have 11) and everyone gives me that error. Of course, with different parameters and such.

Comment: Yeh, that's what I mean, you tried with *Web Service Explorer* (not the axis client) and you got a faulty envelope, isn't that so? Let's narrow it down, make the `verActa()` this: `public String verActa(String alu_dni, String cur_codasign){ return "hello!" }` and call it using the client. If the problem is in the client, it must yield the same error as it is yielding now. If the problem is in the server, the client will work fine this time.

Comment: The problem is the server. The method worked just fine, aka return "hello"".

Comment: OK. Where are you deploying it? Using eclipse? How do you access the database? JDBC? Hibernate?

Comment: Using Eclipse JUNO to develope, Tomcat 6 is deploying the service. The Database is MySQL, Hibernate as persistent layer.

Comment: When you test (and get the expected result), how are you testing the `Servicio` class? Via a `main` method of a class? If so, it is possible that the database access is not being properly executed under tomcat. Does the tomcat have the mysql driver in its `lib/` folder?

Comment: via main method directly on another class who calls the methods from the bussiness layer. I get the expected results on every method. I added the mysql driver (mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar).

Comment: Where did you place it? In the `tomcat\lib` folder? Have you tested the service now via Eclipse's Web Service Explorer?

Comment: Yes, tested it using [this](http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-mysql-datasource-in-tomcat-6/) tutorial. Still no success in the wsdl. And yes, on the lib folder in the tomcat directory.

Comment: How many eclipse projects have you got? `SistemaCapacitacion` only? Where is `Servicio` class? At this project or another? Where are the classes you can successfully use the `main`, also at `SistemaCapacitacion`? I believe we may be facing a classpath issue. That error message (`AxisFault faultCode: ...`) is misleading.

Comment: Servicio class is on SistemaCapacitacion, same goes for the class that uses the main method. I have multiple projects, but I have removed all but the SistemaCapacitacion project from the resources of the server.

Comment: Ok. Can you see some `.wsdd` files in `SistemaCapacitacion` (under `WEB-INF`)? We could edit the `sever-config.wsdd` as described [in this article](http://blogmines.com/blog/2007/02/09/how-to-log-soap-messages-for-a-tomcataxis-web-service/) and see the log with the actual error. We'll then be able to find out if it is a `ClassNotFoundException` error, for instance.

Comment: It's sever-config or server-config? I dont see an sever-config.wsdl file anywhere. Should I paste the file?

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, it is `server-config`. My bad, it was a typo.

Comment: Uhm, its confusing the file. So many entries, I dont really know where to place the three pieces of code. Could I have some guiadance there? Will post the server-config in the main post.

Comment: I added the changed server-config in an answer. Make a backup of your old .wsdd and use the one I pasted.

Comment: So, did you execute it? Is the `axis.log` being generated in the `bin/` folder?

Comment: Okay, made the backup, changed the whole content to your post code, tried the wsdl on the web services explorer and nothing is created on the bin directory of apache. Should it have a specific name?

Comment: Yes, `axis.log`. Search for it in `SistemaCapacitacion\bin` (or use the search tool).

Comment: Searched on the whole PC. No results.

Comment: Ok. Let's try something else. Add the JSP file I put in the answer.

Comment: Hopefully the server will throw the **real** exception and give us some pointers.

Comment: Added the content of the pague localhost:8080/SistemaCapacitacion/index.jsp
in the first post.

Comment: Your program uses a class named `org.orm.PersistentException` and tomcat is unable to find it. In what JAR is it? I searched a bit and it seems to be in some file called `orm.jar` (from visual-paradigm?). If so add it to the `lib/` folder of your tomcat.

Comment: Added that jar, changed the content of the page in the main post.

Comment: As the error says, you have more than one `org.apache.commons.logging.Log` on your classpath. Do your eclipse project have any `commons-logging.jar`? Try removing it from the project (actually, move it somewhere else instead of deleting).

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry, but I really gotta go. It's past 2 AM here (I'm at Brazil) and I gotta be at work by 9 AM. Keep on updating it, I'll help you from there I am as soon as I get to the computer, alright?

Comment: You just edited, I see, you are getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.orm.PersistentManager`. Did you take the `orm.jar` away?

Comment: Okay, np. I just changed the content of the pague. I guess you helped a lot. Don't worry, I'll try to figure the rest (without screwing it up.

Thanks!

Comment: FOr this last problem, try putting the `orm.jar` back into `tomcat\lib`. If it doesnt work, try placing it on `WEB-INF\lib` of `SistemaCapacitacion` instead. Anyway, see ya!!

Comment: No, I didn't take it away.

Comment: Whatever, go and rest, Its late ehre too (almost 2AM) and working this late won't help that much.

Comment: Okay, new edits on the main post. Explained it the best I could.

Comment: Err... Classpath errors are nasty. The current error says you have two `org.apache.commons.logging.Log` in your classpath, meaning there probably are two .JARs with such a class. I know for a fact that `commons-logging.jar` has such a class. Taking it away should solve the problem (if that doesn't bring others), have you tried it? The other strange one is `orm.jar`. How big is it? Can you show us its contents?

Comment: You asked ***what group do I eliminate/move and what group I keep? is there a "good" method to remove them?*** You are talking about dependency (JARs you need and the JARs needed by those JARs) management. The best thing is to use a tool like [Maven](http://obscuredclarity.blogspot.com.br/2012/04/hello-world-maven-m2eclipse-and-eclipse.html), but that's a whole new talk.

Comment: THAT SOLVED IT. I can't believe it was just cause a .jar was duplicated. They added the .jar to the classpath, but I ignored that fact and added to the proyect again at the server. God, you helped me by a lot. Thanks dude, you saved me a big one! How could I pay this to you? :)

Comment: There's absolutely no need to pay :) I'm really glad I could help! I'll try to edit the answer so that it can help somehow anyone with that problem in the future. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSP File:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test JSP</title>
</head>
<body>
HI THERE!
<%= new servicio.Servicio().verActa("1", "1") %>
</body>
</html>
```

Name it `index.jsp`
Add it to your `WebContent\` folder. Make sure there is no other file named `index` or `default`.

Now go to: `http://youserver/SistemaCapacitacion/`